# [Error]: bad characters in classname: (null)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When I am querying for objects from Parse, I get the error: [Error]: bad characters in classname: (null). Here is my querying function:

```
func findEmployeeForLoggedInUser(completion: (array: [PFEmployee], error: String?) -> Void) {
    var query = PFQuery()
    query.whereKey("employerId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in

        var employeeArray = results as? [PFEmployee]

        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String
            if let objects = employeeArray {
                completion(array: objects, error: errorString)
            } else {
                completion(array: [], error: errorString)
            }
        } else {
            if let myObjects = employeeArray {
                for object in myObjects {
                    let object = object as PFEmployee
                }
            }
            completion(array: employeeArray!, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

When I actually want to query for objects, I call the function in a separate file:

```
networking.saveEmployee(employee, completion: { (error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Your employee was saved!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            var alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
            alert.addAction(alertAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            var alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(alertAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
```

I call the function in the viewDidLoad method. `networking` is an instance of my Networking class where the querying function was originally declared. What does this error mean, and what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: HOW PFEMPLOYEE IS BEING CREATED**

```
class PFEmployee: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}
class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Employee"
}
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var jobDesc: String?
@NSManaged var numberOfPoints: Int
@NSManaged var education: String?
@NSManaged var birthday: String?
@NSManaged var employerId: String?
@NSManaged var image: PFFile?
@NSManaged var email: String
@NSManaged var commentary: String?
}
```

Comment: Show how you declared the `PFEmployee` subclass of PFObject in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFQuery needs to be instantiated with a class name:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "PFEmployee")
```

Assuming the class is called PFEmployee in the parse data.